# Ubuntu offline autoinstall ISO

Tags: apt, custom-distributions, cloud-init, curtin, autoinstall

I am migrating an offline autoinstall ISO from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04.

Previously I used the debian-installer preseed file. To disable online mirrors and force an offline install I could use the following line:
`d-i apt-setup/no_mirror boolean true`

Now I use the cloud-init/autoinstall system and my `autoinstall/user-data` YAML file is working fine so far:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  interactive-sections:
    - network
    - keyboard
  ssh:
    install-server: true
```

The following link describes the `apt` section, but nothing is mentioned on offline installations (using only the CD as installation repository): https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apt_source.html

Thank you very much for any hint.

Comment: Would not defining a sources section for apt other then "cd" imply an offline install?